# Cannot find individual KB numbers for patches inside Windows Cumulative Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I have been trying to find a source for the individual patches contained in the new Windows Cumulative Updates, as I would like to be able to compare the KB numbers against the security bulletins.  So far I cannot find the list of contained patches, only an overview.

Are they stored anywhere on the machine (I have checked the registry etc, but only find KBs for the Cumulative Update), if not, is there an online source for this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx and put in your Cumulative Update KB ID, you will get a list of included KB items back.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know if that the only source for this information, as I would really like to do it programmatically (with out creating a web scraping bot)

Comment: Cumulative patches exist in add/remove programs, and obviously the current patch superceeds the previous patch.  It’s not clear what your looking for exactly.  Just a list of CVE addresses In a specific patch?  that exists.

Comment: IS this what your looking for: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4040724? Cumulative updates are not individual updates on Windows 10 it’s a single update. It’s always been like that.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, what I wanted to know was what CVEs (by knowledge base id) are covered by each cumulative update.  I have since found an automated way of solving this issue programmatically (will detail here for posterity), using the [MS Security REST API](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/) you can pull a list of security updates for each month.  Under the Remediations it details the packages that fix the issue etc.

Will mark this as the answer, as it is technically correct.